# Relativistic relative velocity: is $\vec{v}_{A|B}=-\vec{v}_{B|A}$ still true in the relativistic case?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames

Let $S=S_O$ be a stationary frame of reference and $S'=S_A$ and $S''=S_B$ two inertial frames of reference with velocities $\vec{v}_A=\vec{v}_{A|O}$ and $\vec{v}_B=\vec{v}_{B|O}$, as seen in $S_O$. In the non-relativistic case, Gallileo's transformations for speed lead to the relative speed between $S_A$ and $S_B$ being symmetric: 
$$\vec{v}_{A|B}=-\vec{v}_{B|A}$$

Would this relation still be true for the relativistic case? That is, if we drew them in the cartesian coordinate system of $S_O$, would both relative velocities be parallel, with the same magnitude and opposite sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. They have the same magnitude but they don’t have opposite directions. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_velocity#Special_relativity) for the general formula.

The reason is related to two differences between Lorentz boosts and Galilean boosts. First, the order of Lorentz boosts matters; they don’t commute. Second, two non-collinear Lorentz boosts don’t compose to make just a Lorentz boost; there is also a [Wigner rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_rotation).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then, would both relative velocities share the same direction in addition to their magnitude? Wikipedia only has an expression of $\vec{v}_{\mathrm{B} | \mathrm{A}}$, $\vec{v}_{\mathrm{A} | \mathrm{B}}$ written down.

Comment: Just switch A and B. The two relative velocities aren’t antiparallel.

Comment: It is especially apparent when you look at the case for perpendicular velocities, which is shown above the general formula.

Comment: After I answered that “they don’t have opposite directions”, why did you ask “would they share the same direction”? Were you asking if they are *parallel* rather than anti-parallel? No. Neither parallel nor anti-parallel.

Comment: There may be a language issue. I don't know what distinction you are drawing. They don’t point in the same direction. They don’t point in opposite directions. Their directions have *no simple relationship*. Is that clear?

Comment: I see that you deleted a comment to which my previous responded.

Comment: Ok, thanks (I was rewriting it). What I said was that I thought you meant the senses of those vectors instead of the directions. But now, it is clear: $\frac{\vec{v}_{A|B}}{|\vec{v}_{A|B}|} \neq \pm \frac{\vec{v}_{B|A}}{|\vec{v}_{B|A}|}$

Comment: The language issue is that for me antiparallel vectors do not have the same “direction”. They have *opposite* directions. So I never need or use the concept of “sense”. For me, what both parallel and antiparallel vectors have is *collinearity*.

Comment: I’m glad the math result is clear now.

Comment: Forget what I said about collinearity. Parallel and antiparallel vectors are not necessarily collinear.